# Extract Mime Type codecs for MediaSource using FFprobe

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, mime-types, video-codecs

I have to extract the codecs e.g. `'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'` for the MediaSource API. How can I do this strictly with FFprobe/FFmpeg tools? Do not suggest other tools please.

Comment: Not implemented in `ffmpeg` or `ffprobe`.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @StefanFalk unfortunately there is no clean way to get the mime type from FFprobe directly. The only I suppose would work is manually matching the codec tag string, profile, and level parameters to the values in the tables found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter

Comment: @Fr3ddyDev Alright, thanks a lot for providing that link :)

Comment: @StefanFalk glad I was able to help

Comment: @Fr3ddyDev any code you can share mapping ffprobe data to codec mime using the table you shared? if you want to open source it, I would be happy to contribute

Comment: @Yonatan the problem is mostly the amount of variants each format and codec has. There are way too many for a single person to manage. I'm currently working on some safe Rust bindings for FFmpeg's libav* and I'll also try to implement this. A while back I wrote json definitions for ffprobe's output (-print_format json)
https://github.com/FedericoCarboni/ffprobe-json-schema
Here's the FFmpeg mapping for ISO four character IDs and its internal IDs
https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/6.0/isom__tags_8c_source.html#l00029

Comment: @Yonatan you can write to me to the email address on my Github profile if you want to help/need more help

Comment: Thanks @Fr3ddyDev I will take a look it, and will contact you if needed
I also found this article: https://jakearchibald.com/2022/html-codecs-parameter-for-av1/ but it is relevant only for one av1
I wonder how chrome does it, eventually they have to read the file header and decide the codec and settings to decode the file